# Need to modify this log4net to write to a file, with ability to write to many files

Tags: log4net

So I already have nhibernate working which uses log4net, and my web.config currently looks like:

```xml
<log4net debug="false">
  <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender, log4net">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default priority -->
  <root>
    <priority value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Now my current requirement is the ability to create a seperate log file for each major module that I have in my application.

Right now it seems to be just writing to console, but I need to add the ability to write to files.

What do I have to modify in my configuration to be able to do this?

I want to be able to, in my code, say I want to write to logfile "logfile_1", and if it doesn't exist, create it, otherwise just append to it.

Answer (score 2):

Really simple, rinse and repeat as required for number of files you want, you can also associate namespaces with different files if you want them separated out that way but I find it easier just to use Log2Console to view the file all together.

```xml
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file value="k:\temp\log2console.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j" />
</appender>
```

Don't forget to add the appender-ref to your root section.

Comment: Additionally, you can use the RollingFileAppender which has a more robust feature set for auto-archiving or auto-backup of files that reach a certain size or date.

[RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.html)

Comment: can't I set it up such that I don't have to define the name of the filename?

Comment: @codecompleting: Creating your own appenders is fairly trivial so if you wanted the same functionality with a slight difference on the file value I'm sure you could create it.  I haven't looked into it too much since I usually want to know what and where my log files are for a given application.

Comment: but if I have more than 1 appender, how to I specify which appender in my code?

Comment: I want to make sure this fileappender doesn't effect the previous console appender that is wired up.  Will it effect how log4net was setup previously? thanks!

Comment: No the appenders are independent of each other so you can add as many appenders as you want and unless you are doing something like writing to the same file with multiple appenders they should not conflict with each other.